# mapping between function void pointer and function pointer

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have implemented a generic linked list in the c language:

```
typedef struct ListElmt_{
    void *data;
    struct ListElmt_ *nextElmt;
} ListElmt;

typedef struct _List {
    ListElmt *head;
    ListElmt *tail;
    unsigned long size; 
    void (*destroy)(void *data);
    void (*match)(void *fdata, *sdata);
}List;
```

But I'm confronted to a problem that break generic of my linked list, when i want the data to be a function pointer, the conversion from pointer to function to a pointer is not safe.
I have tried to use the union to solve the problem.

```
typedef struct ListElmt_{
    typedef union {
        void *data;
        void (*fct)();
    }
    struct ListElmt_ *nextElmt;
} ListElmt;
```

Comment: Take a close look at the function "pointer" in the union, it's a function that returns a pointer, not a pointer to a function. Also, you can't have two members with the same name.

Comment: yes, thanks just inattention mistake

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem, is, but a `void` pointer can point to *anything*, including a function. So I don't really see the need to have a union with two pointers, of which one is a generic pointer that can point to anything. You just have to type-cast the original ´data` pointer correctly when you use it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The C standard doesn't guarantee that a `void *` can safely hold a function pointer, just the address of any object.

Comment: @karim: The problem with using a `union` is that all your other functions would have to change, too. In other words, even if you have a separate union member to store a function pointer, you'd also have to have, say, an `insert()` function that accepted a function pointer, rather than a `void *`. There is no generic pointer in C that's guaranteed to be able to hold both object and function pointers, so you can't get it as generic as you want without resorting to implementation-defined behavior.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Good point, I always forget that pointers to functions are a little special compared to other pointers. Though in reality, and on a normal PC-like system, a `void*` should be able to handle pointers to functions.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Yes, agreed, on normal systems chances are good that it'll work anyway.